# onOpen() function gets triggered on desktop but not on Android

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onOpen() {  
Logger.log("start");  
Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName());  
}
```

The function gets triggered every time I open or refresh my spreadsheet on the desktop as expected but it doesn't get trigger when I open on Android sheets app. I tried clearing cache too but no help!
The onEdit() function works as expected on the Android app.

**I just want the onOpen() function to get triggered when any user with editing rights to the sheet opens the sheet on the Android app!**

Comment: Yeah the mobile apps leave a lot to be desired.  I never use them.

Comment: You should submit a feature request on the Google Apps Script issue tracker or if it already exists star it. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request for Google.

Comment: What makes you think the `onOpen` is not running? Have you checked the `Executions` tab?

Comment: Yesss obviously!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This might be a bug:

Sheets `onOpen` triggers ([simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) or [installed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)) do not fire when the spreadsheet is opened in mobile.

#### Reported in Issue Tracker:

This has been previously reported in Issue Tracker, and already [filed internally by Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765325#comment7):

- [onOpen event in Android mobile app does not fire triggers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765325)

I'd suggest you to [subscribe to this issue by starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track and to help prioritizing it.

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue had been filed 4 years ago, I don't see any correction any soon :(